# Wavemaker Project - I added security, now my will show a blank page

Tags: security, wavemaker

I have been using Wavemaker Studion (v.6.7) for around 3 months and it is a pretty good RAD application.

A few weeks ago, I added the security feature (Database) on a 40% finished project and when I launch the project, it shows a **blank page** - let me mention that the project was running flawless before. I didn’t notice that it was related to the security feature.

Then I started a new project, on which I re added the security service (Database again)...when I clicked the Run button, the project will again launch with a blank page, even when I remove the feature - by the way, everytime I uncheck the enable security checkbox, then save the project, it keeps recheck everytime i reopen the security tab with the settings as if I have never unchecked the checkbox earlier.

I tried to tweak a bit the security features and the login page appeared but the credentials will be invalid ( which is strange as I used simple ones as admin and pass). There won’t be anyway for me to fix this as the project seems to be corrupted.

My main concern is not to be able to successfully setup the security with Database security provider.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check "Show login page" box for you can see the login page, then you can enter with the "user" and "pass".

Comment: Thank you @enrique-san-martin